# I am trying to npx create react app after downloading node js

Tags: node.js, npm, module, node-modules, npx

I installed the recommended node js on my system, and any time I try to npx create react app, I get this error..

```
C:\Users\STARDAWG>npx create-react-app closesellers
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@npmcli/config'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\STARDAWG\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\config\definition.js
- C:\Users\STARDAWG\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\config\definitions.js
- C:\Users\STARDAWG\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\config\index.js
- C:\Users\STARDAWG\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npx-cli.js
←[90m    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> ←[90m(C:\Users\STARDAWG\←[39mAppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4mnpm←[24m\lib\utils\config\definition.js:33:5←[90m)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: [
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\STARDAWG\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\utils\\config\\definition.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\STARDAWG\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\utils\\config\\definitions.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\STARDAWG\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\utils\\config\\index.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\STARDAWG\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npx-cli.js'←[39m
  ]
}

Node.js v18.16.0
```

I have tried deleting node js app and  file and installing them again

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you made the following steps:

1. You have installed create-react-app with the command `npm install -g create-react-app`. Make sure you added the `-g` flag in order to install globaly.
2. You have restarted your editor or even better your computer.|
3. Now go to your project folder and run this commands in order

   **npm install -g create-react-app**

   **npx create-react-app my-app**

Basically you do the same thing just to be sure.

If nothing from the above works try `npm cache clean --force` and try again.

Comment: I had this error with a Stardog tutorial https://docs.stardog.com/tutorials/build-a-react-app and "npm cache clean" did the trick.